# Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField'

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I get the error that cause me can't display the page:
**Extender control 'ModalPopupMutlipleClient' cannot extend 'hfPopup'. Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField'.**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Extender control 'ModalPopupMutlipleClient' cannot extend 'hfPopup'. Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField'.

AND at my webpage

```html
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMutipleClient" runat="server" style="display: none;" class="ModalPanel" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" CssClass="modalPopup" Width="1175px" Height="600px">

  <table style="width: 1170px;" class="topBanner">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%;"></td>
      <td>
        <asp:Label id="lbl" runat="server" Text="Press [Esc] to Exit Full Screen Mode"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 25%;">
        <asp:HyperLink id="closePopup" runat="server" CssClass="ClosePopupCls">Close [x]</asp:HyperLink>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ShowZoomControl="false" ShowPrintButton="false" AsyncRendering="False" SizeToReportContent="True" ZoomPercent="85" Width="100%" ClientIDMode="Static">
  </rsweb:ReportViewer>
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPopup" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupMutlipleClient" popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" CancelControlID="closePopup" OnCancelScript="cancelClick();" runat="server" BehaviorID="ModalPopup" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
  PopupControlID="pnlMutipleClient" TargetControlID="hfPopup" />
```

May I know how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of `AjaxControlToolkit` you have use? The problem originated from `AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopup.ModalPopupExtender` class that doesn't include `[TargetControlType(typeof(HiddenField))]` attribute on certain version (see https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/228) for details). I suggest you change `TargetControlID` attribute at `ModalPopupMutlipleClient` to other control implementing `HtmlControl` or `WebControl` (e.g. `TextBox` with `style="display:none;"`).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto currently i'm using version 16.1.1.0...is that any version that can support it?

Comment: In previous versions `ModalPopupExtender` works fine when extending `HiddenField`, hence this weird behavior only occurs in version 16.1.1 (current version at the time this comment written). As a workaround for your AjaxControlToolkit version, try using `asp:Label` or `asp:Button` which replaces `asp:HiddenField` (e.g. `<asp:Label ID="hfPopup" ... style="display:none;" />`) until the bug officially fixed.